# JavaFX textarea doesn't display changed value

Tags: user-interface, tabs, javafx, updating

Hello guys i'm using jdk 1.8 with NetBeans version 8 and SceneBuilder 2.2. I have files Main.fxml and MainController that have 2 tabs and a TextArea at the bottom which is supposed to print out status info.

Login.fxml is a tab which i attached to Main.fxml first tab through include in scenebuilder. 
It has its own controllers and a button that need to print info to the TextArea in MainController. I can access the TextArea with FXMLLoader and change the value but it doesn't update in the UI. Let's say @FXML LogID is the TextArea in MainController and this is the code in LoginController:

@FXML
    private Button btn;

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            try {
                FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
                fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
                AnchorPane pane = fxmlLoader.load();
                MainController control = (MainController) fxmlLoader.getController();

                new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                control.LogID.appendText("Hello");
                                System.out.println(control.LogID.getText()); 
                                //prints "hello" in console but not the ui
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }).start();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(LoginController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I tried this with a stand alone program and it runs just fine !

Comment: Since you said it worked I re-installed everything on my Ubuntu laptop tried it again and same thing. Nothing shows up when I change text in labels or textareas from LoginController. I can call methods in MainController and everything works except updating the UI. And this is only if i try to update the MainController from any of my tabs.

Answer (score 0):

After about a week of trying everything I can I came up with a different solution.
This will update it without using FXMLLoader();

All i did was give the Login.fxml anchorpane an fx:id and kept printing getParent() to console until i got root so..
@FXML AnchorPane paneID; // In LoginController.java

//In platform.runLater i ran the bottom code

TextArea area = (TextArea) paneID.getParent().getParent().getParent().lookup("#LogID");
                        area.appendText("Hello\n");

first getParent was the tab content area

second tabpane

third the main anchorpane